# ¿Comunicacion HTML con java?

Tags: java, html, hibernate

estoy trabajando en una pequeña prueba donde hice una tabla de datos en mysql y use hibernate para generar el pojo, la ingnieria inversa y el archivo de configurcion de hibernate cfg en xml. Hice un pequeño formulario en html para tratar de ingresar los datos y almacenarlos en la base de datos, pero aun  soy muy nuevo en esto y no se como comunicar html con java, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="PersonalInf.java" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Id" >
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" >
            <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido">
            <input type="text" name="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
            <input type="number" name="edad" placeholder="Edad">
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

y aqui dejo el codigo de hibernate:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controlador;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import  Modelo.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Aldo
 */        
public class Funcion {

    public void altaUsuarios(PersonalInf user){

        SessionFactory sesion= NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session;
        session=sesion.openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save (user);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insertado correctamente");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir estos enlaces. Me han ayudado a comprender ciertas cosas que no entendía bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es que si estas trabajando con hibernate uses JPA 2 y apliques las plantillas thymeleaf o jsp. SpringBoot. Aqui te dejo un par de ejemplos que me sirvieron a mi cuando empece con hibernate.

[ejemplo 1](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-example)

[ejemplo 2](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-oracle-example/)

[ejemplo 3](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-5-example)